# How do I call a where function in a Laravel view?

Tags: laravel, lumen

Is there a way to use a where statement in a view?

In the second select input, I want to list all the makes of vehicles in the previously selected year.

```
<select data-placeholder="&nbsp;Year" class="chzn-select year" style="width:70px;" tabindex="1" id="year">
    <option value=""></option>
    @foreach($data['vehicle_years'] as $vehicle)
      <option value="{{ $vehicle->year }}">{{ $vehicle->year }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<select data-placeholder="&nbsp;Year" class="chzn-select year" style="width:70px;" tabindex="1" id="year">
    <option value=""></option>
    @foreach($data['vehicle_makes'] as $vehicle)
        <option value="{{ $vehicle->make }}">{{ $vehicle->make }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

So maybe something along the lines of:

```
{{ $vehicle->make->where(...) }}
```

Comment: To do on the fly, you'd need AJAX to return the results. Put simply, post/get to a route and return the results, use jQuery to append them in the second select

Comment: Is there some recommended documentation on how to do this somewhere? Not sure I completely understand.

Comment: Take a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250774/how-to-show-ajax-response-in-product-grid/46252134#46252134 It might give you some hints on how to go about it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use where() anywhere in a blade in this way:

```
{{ $vehicle->where('make', $make)->get() }}
```

But, if you come up with using eloquent in a view, it means there is something wrong in code design. Here are some suggestions:

After the first select is selected by the user, you need to reload the page with selected make, then, you can use it in where() statement in the code design you have now. If there will be no reload, you cannot state what to put in where(). If you will reload the page, then, actually you do not need to use where() in blade..

If you are panning to use the where() in a loop in view, it is better to load all "vehicles and makes" in the controller (if number of items is not too big), and use them (you may need some js)

Alternatively, you may use AJAX to get list of "make" after the vehicle is selected, as it is mentioned in comments.

Answer (score -2):

!!You should not have both selects as the same ID!!

Remember that PHP code is being generated on the backend before it is sent to the client, so it's not possible to use blade to supply a dynamic list unless you are using AJAX to call a new list based on the year and replace the old one. This is heavy lifting though. If you don't have large amounts of data, I'd suggest using regular jQuery to show/hide those that don't match the correct year (maybe by the year being a class). Even better would be to use Vue.js and use v-if to check if the option matches the year selected above.

See Laracasts - Learn Vue 2 (Episode 6) for more details on that.

Here is a quick version of the jQuery answer:

```
<select data-placeholder="&nbsp;Year" class="chzn-select year" style="width:70px;" tabindex="1" id="year">
   <option value=""></option>
   @foreach($data['vehicle_years'] as $vehicle)
      <option value="{{ $vehicle->year }}">{{ $vehicle->year }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>

<select data-placeholder="&nbsp;Year" class="chzn-select year" style="width:70px;" tabindex="1" id="make">
   <option value=""></option>
   @foreach($data['vehicle_makes'] as $vehicle)
      <option class="{{ $vehicle->year }}" value="{{ $vehicle->make }}">{{ $vehicle->make }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>



<script>
   $(function() {

      var year = $('select#year');

      year.change(function() {

         var makes = $('select#make > option');

         makes.show(); // shows all

         // hides all that don't have the selected year as class
         makes.each(function( index ) {
             if ( !$(this).hasClass( year.val() ) ) $(this).hide();
         });

      });

   });
</script>
```

Comment: To whomever downvoted my answer, it is a common courtesy to not just downvote an answer without expressing why you feel that way. Otherwise your vote doesn't help anyone..

Comment: You are correct @GoogleMac comments should be enforced when down voting is done. However, I also found some issues with your answer. It didn't directly answer the OP'S question rather it addreses an issue with his code. Maybe you can make it clear what part of the post your answer targets so that others don't confuse it as a answer. Btw I was not the one who down voted your answer.

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi, the first line of my answer pointed out a mistake I noticed. I then put a small bit of info for the OP in case he or others weren't aware. Then I finished with a quick answer in jQuery. I probably could structure it a bit better though.. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I think its better to structure it in clear format and if you have the answer to the OP's question, it will do well if you simply update the answer with it otherwise you might get enough downvotes before the end of the day (if people don't read these comments)